Do you say "he makes money selling saliva" to mean he makes money out of his talking skills?
Sometimes, "to sell saliva" (literally translated) to mean to make money by just using his/her talking skills, normally with a negative meaning. It often used to refer to middlemen.
Say you go to Japan and setup a business there but you don't speak Japanese. So, you ask a Japanese friend to convince Japanese customers to buy your service/products.
Can you to the Japanese friend "you just make money selling your saliva. It's not a hard job"?
In other situations, it carries a negative meaning. A company has engineers and marketers. Engineers create products but make less money than marketers For example, "he makes more money than any engineer in my company by just selling his saliva"

It's not an English idiom.

I’ve never heard the idiom. Where have you encountered it?

@PaulTanenbaum, I translated it from Vietnamese to English

Selling saliva is NOT an English idiom. In English, usually, bodily secretions (urine, faeces, saliva, snot, semen, blood, etc) are considered unappetising ('gross').

We do have the informal term to spitball (to throw out new ideas by engaging in spontaneous and unfiltered brainstorming). But it relates to creativity, not marketing.

@MichaelHarvey, and making money by just using your convincing / marketing verbal skills is smelly. God doesn't like it.

Tom - exactly so.

In my house, we call saliva 'goz', and one of the things we find creepy about American TV dramas and films is the way random people go to an (invariably) huge refrigerator, get out a huge container of milk or orange juice, drink directly from it, replace the lid, and put it back, making us go 'Yuk! Their goz all over the spout!'.

@MichaelHarvey, I hate that too. These people want to raise germs in the milk.

Unlike some other proverbs and idioms, this one doesn't translate well. In English, saliva is not particular associated with talking. It is associated with eating  "He salivated at the sight of the steak".  Or by extension  "He salivated at the sight of the beautiful girl".  There is something brutish about this.  Saliva and spit are produced when we see something delicious, but are themselves disgusting.
So "selling saliva" would not suggest using talking skills. A nice high-class word to use is "eloquence" or "eloquent".  "He makes more money than any engineer in my company by just being eloquent"

+1 for 'brutish'.

@James K +2 for the good answer!
